# Find a solution to the quadratic equation $2x^2+y^2+2yz+2z^2=0.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the finite field $F= \mathbb{F}_7$ of $7$ elements. Find an explicit nonzero solution $(x,y,z) \in F^3$ to the quadratic equation $$2x^2+y^2+2yz+2z^2=0.$$

I tried manipulating the form of the equation a bit: $$2x^2+y^2+2yz+2z^2=2x^2+(y+z)^2+z^2=0$$ but couldn't seem to get it in a form where a nonzero solution is obvious. I tried plugging in $(1,1,1) \in \mathbb{F}_7^3$ and found that $2(1)^2+(1+1)^2+(1)^2=2+4+1=7$. Since $7 \equiv 0 \mod 7$, does this solution work? How could I further simplify the equation to arrive at a nonzero solution without arriving at a lucky guess?

Comment: I don't think that you can get anything simpler than a diagonal form!

Comment: @Crostul Sorry...I meant there are no solutions that give answer =$0$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the squares in $F$ are $\{ x^2 : x \in F\} = \{ 0,1,2,4 \}$. Since $2=5^2 = (3^{-1})^2$ you can look for solutions of the equation
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=0$$
and then apply the (invertible linear) transformation $x=3a, y=b-c, z=c$.

Now, solutions of $a^2+b^2+c^2=0$ are easy to find: they are exactly $(0,0,0)$ and the 6 permutations of $(1,2,4)$; we can conclude that there are 6 nontrivial solutions.

Comment: also permutations of $(3,5,6)$

Comment: More like $2^6$ nontrivial solutions.

Comment: Perhaps $48=2^3.3!$ nontrivial solutions?

Comment: @Michael You are right! Every nonzero square has two distinct roots, so there are 48 nontrivial solutions.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  2x^2+y^2+2yz+2z^2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 7\\ 
  2x^2 + (y^2 + 2yz + z^2) + z^2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 7\\  
  2x^2 + (y+z)^2 + z^2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 7
\end{align}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  n\pmod 7   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \hline
  n^2\pmod 7 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

A possible solution is

\begin{align}
  2x^2 &\equiv 4 \pmod 7 \\
  (y+z)^2 &\equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\
  z^2 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
  \implies \\
  x     &\in \{3,4\} \pmod 7 \\
  (y+z) &\in \{3,4\} \pmod 7 \\
  z     &\in \{1,6\} \pmod 7 \\
\end{align}

Which gives

$(x,y,z) \in
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
  (3,2,1),& (3,4,6),& (4,2,1),& (4,4,6), \\
  (3,3,1),& (3,5,6),& (4,3,1),& (4,5,6)
\end{array}
\right\}$

Another possibility is

\begin{align}
  2x^2    &\equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\
  (y+z)^2 &\equiv 4 \pmod 7 \\
  z^2     &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
  \implies \\
  x     &\in \{1,6\} \pmod 7 \\
  (y+z) &\in \{2,5\} \pmod 7 \\
  z     &\in \{1,6\} \pmod 7 \\
\end{align}

Which gives

$(x,y,z) \in
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
  (1,1,1),& (1,3,6),& (6,1,1),& (6,3,6), \\
  (1,4,1),& (1,6,6),& (6,4,1),& (6,6,6)
\end{array}
\right\}$

There may be more solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a taste of something that comes later. It is not just that we can solve $2 p^2 + q^2 + r^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ with $(p,q,r)$ not all divisible by $7,$ we can actually solve $2 p^2 + q^2 + r^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {7^k}$ with $(p,q,r)$ not all divisible by $7,$ for arbitrarily large positive $k.$

It is most convenient to take your $x=z$ and write $(y+z)^2 + 3 z^2,$ and call that $u^2 + 3 v^2.$ We can actually solve $u^2 + 3 v^2 = 7^n,$ with $u,v$ not divisible by $7.$ 
$$ 2^2 + 3 \cdot 1^2 = 7,  $$ 
$$ 1^2 + 3 \cdot 4^2 = 49,  $$ 
$$ (-10)^2 + 3 \cdot 9^2 = 343= 7^3,  $$
$$ (-47)^2 + 3 \cdot 8^2 = 2401 = 7^4,  $$
and so on.
Indeed, given
$$ u_n^2 + 3 v_n^2 = 7^n, $$ we get
$$ u_{n+1}^2 + 3 v_{n+1}^2 = 7^{n+1}, $$
where
$$u_{n+1} = 2 u_n - 3 v_n,  $$
$$ v_{n+1} = u_n + 2 v_n.  $$
A theorem from linear algebra called Cayley Hamilton allows us to write this as two Fibonacci type sequences,
$$ u_{n+2} = 4 u_{n+1} - 7 u_n,  $$
$$ v_{n+2} = 4 v_{n+1} - 7 v_n.  $$
So, the separate sequences are
$$ u_n = \{2, 1, -10, -47, -118, -143, 254, 2017, 6290, 11041, \ldots \} $$
$$ v_n = \{1, 4, 9, 8, -31, -180, -503, -752, 513, 7316, \ldots \} $$
Oh, induction shows that $u_n$ and $v_n$ never become divisible by $7,$ as
$$ u_{n+2} \equiv 4 u_{n+1} \pmod 7,  $$
$$ v_{n+2} \equiv 4 v_{n+1} \pmod 7.  $$

Even though we are squaring $u_n$ and $v_n,$ it is natural to allow them to become negative or positive as the sequences dictate. These will alternate sign from time to time, as the roots of $\lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 7$ are $2 \pm i \sqrt 3.$ The argument of these is about $41^\circ,$ so there is a rough cycle of about 9 terms to reach about $360^\circ.$ Each of the sequences should be positive for about four or five consecutive values, then negative for about five or four values.

Answer (score 1):

A more purely geometric take on the problem:

As others have remarked, the original is $0=2x^2+y^2+2yz+2z^2=(3x)^2 + (y+z)^2+z^2$, so by setting $X=3x$, $Y=y+z$, and $Z=z$, we get $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=0$. Since there are no nontrivial solutions with $Z=0$, we can set $Z=1$ and dehomogenize to get $X^2+Y^2+1=0$, a conic in the plane, which has the solution-point $(2,4)$ (among others).

Now, just as you can find the rational points on the (real) unit circle by drawing the lines of rational slope through $(-1,0)$ and locating the other intersection, here we can take the line of slope $m$ through $(2,4)$ and find the other intersection with our curve. Before writing down the formulas, let me point out what we know as of now: each $m\in\Bbb F_7$ gives a different point on our curve $X^2+Y^2+1=0$, that’s seven right there, and there’s the intersection with the line of “infinite” slope through $(2,4)$, i.e. the point $(2,3)$ as well. That’s eight points on our dehomogenized curve, and if you want *all* the solutions over $\Bbb F_7$, you take the points $(a,b,1)$ that we’ve found on the homogeneous curve, and multiply by each of the nonzero elements of $\Bbb F_7$, to give $48$ solutions in all.

If anyone wants to check my computations, the other intersection of the curve $X^2+Y^2+1=0$ with the line $Y-4=m(X-2)$ has
\begin{align}
x_m&=\frac{5+6m+2m^2}{1+m^2}\\
y_m&=mx_m+5m+4\,.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Given $2x^2+y^2+2yz+2z^2=0$, we get $2x^2+y^2+2yz+z^2+z^2=0$ and $2x^2+(y+z)^2+z^2=0$ or
$(y+z)^2+z^2=-2x^2$ or
$[(y+z)/x]^2+(z/x)^2=-2$

I don't see why the sum of two squares should be negative.

Comment: It is clear that you are not familiar with the field of 7 elements, where there is no notion of positive and negative.